# Determinant of 2-forms

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I have matrix 4x4 and elements of the matrix are 2-forms. How to calculate determinant (in Mathematica 11) if this matrix using external product instead of normal product? I use components of Riemann tensor of forth rank RUddd and calculate 2-form of curvature

```
rt[a_, b_] := 
 Sum[FullSimplify[RUddd][[a, k, b, l]] TensorWedge[x[k], x[l]], {k, 1,
    4}, {l, 1, 4}]
```

Then make matrix

```
Mrt = Table[
    rt[a, b], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 1, 4}] /. {x[1]\[TensorWedge]x[1] -> 0, 
    x[2]\[TensorWedge]x[2] -> 0, x[3]\[TensorWedge]x[3] -> 0, 
    x[4]\[TensorWedge]x[4] -> 0};
```

and then obtain matrix which I need

```
gg = (DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + I/(2 \[Pi]) Mrt);
```

Now I need to calculate determinant of this matrix but using wedge product instead of normal product.

Comment: Is this about the software _Mathematica_ by Wolfram?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to solve by using Mathematica 11

Comment: Then please post the code you already have for the matrix (elements).

Comment: @ Marius Ladegård Meyer I added code. Because product of 2-forms is commutative I calculated determinant with normal product and after calculation I changed by hand product of 2-forms for wedge product. But I think it possible to calculate by using power of Mathematica.

Comment: Can you, please, clarify two items for me.  First, how should `x[1]` be interpreted?  Is it your symbol for the 1-form basis?  Or, is it a numeric array?  I'm thinking that is all it could be, to be used with `TensorWedge[]`.  Second, the `gg[[1,1]]` component looks to me like a scalar added to the sum of wedge products of the 1-form basis.  For me it looks like a scalar added to a 2-form basis.  When the determinant of `gg` is expanded, it looks like there would be scalars added to 2-forms added to 4-forms, etc.

Comment: @ LouisB Yes for all. x[k] are 1-forms and determinant is sum of scalar and 2-forms and 4 forms. This is Chern determinant. TensorWedge[x[1],x[1]] is not zero because I can explain to Mathematica that x[k] are 1-forms, but I did not find how to declare this. In package of Bananos http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/EDC/ExteriorDifferentialCalculus.html it is possible to declare and then TensorWedge[x[1],x[1]] =0. But I need to change Times -> TensorWedge in calculation of determinant and Bananos package can't this.